# KDE on Ubuntu 15.04 - Missing .desktop Icons

Tags: icons, kde, .desktop

I installed plasma 5.3 on my ubuntu machine and I am encountering a strange problem. 
Some application icons are just not displayed: this happens only with kde, while with other DE (unity, gnome and gnome fallback) icons are properly displayed.

Even with .desktop entries that were created by me, there is no icon shown.

[image]
[image]

As you can see, in the second image no icon is displayed for "Mail", even though on the desktop the launcher is properly displayed.

How could I solve this issue?

This is the .desktop file for "Mail"

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=Webapp for outlook.com
Exec=qmlscene /Applications/Mail/Main.qml
Icon=/home/carloalberto/Downloads/outlook_icon.png
Name[en_US]=Mail
Name=Mail
Path=/Applications/Mail/
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

But anyways, this doesn't happen only with my custom .desktop entries, as you can see

Comment: Do your .desktop files validate with `desktop-file-validate`? And does running `sudo update-desktop-database` help at all? (I'm assuming not, because I've got exactly the same trouble and those things don't help!)

Answer (score 0):

- in `systemsettings -> icons`
- Select Breeze
- `systemssettings -> application style -> graphic components -> icons`
- Select Breeze
- `systemssettings -> application style -> gnome application style(GTK)`
- Select Icon theme = Breeze
- Fallback theme (IMPORTANT) = Oxygen
- restart

References: [here](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/no-icons-in-kde-after-update/6806/2)